# Вопрос по поводу глобальных переменных

Tags: javascript

Я отдаю себе отчет о том, что это супер нубский вопрос, но тем не менее, я просидел час в попытках понять, почему глоабальный вар изменяется. Я делаю глобальный вар аргументом функции, на основе этого аргумента делаю новый лет, после этого изменяю только его.  Почему глобальный вар тоже изменяется? Еще раз простите, но я даже не знаю, как загуглить вопрос правильно.

```js
var bookList = ["The Hound of the Baskervilles", "On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies", "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica", "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae"];

function add(booklist, bookName) {
  let meh = booklist;
  meh.push(bookName);
  return meh;

}

var newBookList = add(bookList, 'A Brief History of Time');

console.log(bookList);
```

консоль показывает измененный буклист.

Comment: Массивы в JavaScript - это тип объекта. `console.log(typeof bookList); // -> object`. Объекты и массивы передаются по ссылке. Гуглите *Передача параметров по значению и по ссылке*

Answer (score 2):

Просто скопипащу

> Обычные значения: строки, числа, булевы значения, null/undefined при
>   присваивании переменных копируются целиком или, как говорят, «по
>   значению».
>
> С объектами – всё не так.
>
> В переменной, которой присвоен объект, хранится не сам объект, а
>   «адрес его места в памяти», иными словами – «ссылка» на него.

Таким образом у тебя в переменной `meh` находится не скопированный массив, а ссылка на него и ты в него добавляешь элемент.

Comment: Можно дописать про трюк копирования массива) `let meh = booklist.slice(0);`

Comment: Я считаю, что надо оставлять людям какой-то простор для творчества и повод более глубоко вникнуть в тему